# OneNote seems to filling up my diskspace when I leave OneNote open and I don't know why?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I have changed backups to 0 and it still happens. Multiple users are accessing the same notebook. My hard drive will go from 120G free to > 1G free.

The way I recover the lost disk space is by running Save & Backup/Optimize All Files Now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the issue One Note, or, One Drive.  I have One Drive turned off, and One Note does not use much disk space.

Comment: OneNote, I am not using One Drive. C: drive is the drive that is filling up.

Comment: It hasn't done it for about a week now, so I am assuming something updated to fix it.